local functions with lambdas - put them inside or outside for loop?
Code 1:
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Vector2d {
    public:
        double x, y;
        Vector2d(double x, double y) : x(x), y(y) { }
};

int main() {
    const double FoV = 50.0;
    std::vector<Vector2d> vecOfVector2d;
    vecOfVector2d.emplace_back(Vector2d(2.0, 3.0));
    vecOfVector2d.emplace_back(Vector2d(4.0, 5.0));
    
    for (std::vector<Vector2d>::const_iterator i = vecOfVector2d.begin(); i != vecOfVector2d.end(); ++i) {
        const Vector2d vec = *i;
        double xpos = rand() % 100; // Calculated but varies in each iteration
        
        auto isBBoxInsideFOVHorizontal = [FoV, xpos, vec]()->bool{
                std::cout << xpos << " " << vec.x << " " << vec.y << std::endl;
                return true;
        };
        
        isBBoxInsideFOVHorizontal();

    }
    
    return 0;
}

Code 2:
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Vector2d {
    public:
        double x, y;
        Vector2d(double x, double y) : x(x), y(y) { }
};

int main() {
    const double FoV = 50.0;
    std::vector<Vector2d> vecOfVector2d;
    vecOfVector2d.emplace_back(Vector2d(2.0, 3.0));
    vecOfVector2d.emplace_back(Vector2d(4.0, 5.0));
    
    auto isBBoxInsideFOVHorizontal = [FoV](const double xpos, const Vector2d vec)->bool{ 
                std::cout << xpos << " " << vec.x << " " << vec.y << std::endl;
                return true;
    };
        
    for (std::vector<Vector2d>::const_iterator i = vecOfVector2d.begin(); i != vecOfVector2d.end(); ++i) {
        const Vector2d vec = *i;
        double xpos = rand() % 100; // Calculated but varies in each iteration
        
        isBBoxInsideFOVHorizontal(xpos, vec);
    }
    
    return 0;
}

Code 3:
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Vector2d {
    public:
        double x, y;
        Vector2d(double x, double y) : x(x), y(y) { }
};

int main() {
    const double FoV = 50.0;
    std::vector<Vector2d> vecOfVector2d;
    vecOfVector2d.emplace_back(Vector2d(2.0, 3.0));
    vecOfVector2d.emplace_back(Vector2d(4.0, 5.0));
    
    for (std::vector<Vector2d>::const_iterator i = vecOfVector2d.begin(); i != vecOfVector2d.end(); ++i) {
        const Vector2d vec = *i;
        double xpos = rand() % 100; // Calculated but varies in each iteration
        
        auto isBBoxInsideFOVHorizontal = [FoV](const double xpos, const Vector2d vec)->bool{ 
                std::cout << xpos << " " << vec.x << " " << vec.y << std::endl;
                return true;
        };
        isBBoxInsideFOVHorizontal(xpos, vec);
    }
    
    return 0;
}

All 3 versions work. Although, this piece of code (local function) should be kept inside the for loop where it belongs conceptually. The for loop is really long and putting this small local function thousands of lines above should be avoided in this case.
Could someone explain clearly if Code 1 (and 3) create multiple structures or has any kind of additional computational burden? Especially in the case of Code 3, keeping FoV (that never changes) in the capture list creates any problem (such as multiple creation of functors)?
OR Codes 1, 2 and 3 are 100% equivalent in compilation/execution terms (of course bear in mind this is just a MWE for discussion and so that you can compile it, actual structures might differ)?

There is no reason in case 2 that you cannot move the lambda function inside the loop. Isn't that the best of both worlds (in your terms)?

A non capturing lambda isn't implemented with functor objects, it's just a normal function. In both sets of code the compiler will just inline your lambda anyway. Use whichever code makes your code easier to read

Easier to read should be your guideline. Notice how in Code 1 there are no arguments to the function call. At the call site it is not obvious what the call operates on. This may not be a problem here since the definition is right above the call. But if there is some distance between the definition and the call, it might obscure rather than help.

OK. But I also want to give access to some const variables as well. For example another is "const double FoV = 50.0" which is a const way up above my code. Shouldn't that be placed inside capturing brackets [] and therefore some things will change regarding what you were saying for initial MWE? @AlanBirtles

@john I am kinda leaning towards that solution tbh. But I am totally wondering why the [] are for if I just put everything as argument? I searched for it and only thing I could find is for the case where lambdas are used to do for loops as "wrapper" functions".

In your situation, I'd lean toward option 2 (the lambda defined before the loop, and passes xpos and vec as arguments).   Creating the lambda in the loop with capture values requires creating a data structure containing copies of the captured values on each loop iteration, which has a cost and is unnecessary.    I'd also pass vec by reference, not by value (which often means copying, unless copy elision is in play).   Aside:  use a range-based for such as for (const auto &vec: vecOfVector2D) rather than manually using iterators and dereferencing - let the compiler earn its keep,

@Tetix You cannot define local functions in C++ unless they are lambda functions. So if you want a local function you must use []. However as Alan Birtles said, if your lambda function does not capture anything then it is implemented in exactly the same way as a regular function, so in this case the [] is present just because that's what the syntax of C++ requires.

If you want to know the answer used Compiler Explorer. Simply paste your code into the window and it show what it compiles to. https://godbolt.org You can try it with different compilers and optimisation options to see if that makes a difference.

In both of these examples, you're executing the functor immediately inside the loop, and never anywhere else. In such a case, both versions are essentially equivalent, and you can use whichever you want.
Version 2 is no different from defining a normal function and executing it inside the loop. In fact, if you're just trying to clean up your code, I'd recommend just implementing a separate function or private method within the enclosing class - it may not appear as clean at first, as it'll separate the code, but it'll help with maintainability in the long run, as it leads to smaller functions with more isolated and well defined effects.
Version 1 is worth special attention in a more general case because of its ability to capture values. This is equivalent to binding arguments to a function. This is especially useful if you wish for a delayed execution of the function at a later point in time, rather than executing that logic within the loop immediately after it's defined.
As an example, I modified your code to show this specific use case:
class Vector2d {
public:
  double x, y;
  Vector2d(double x, double y) : x(x), y(y) { }
};

int main() {
  const double FoV = 50.0;
  std::vector<Vector2d> vecOfVector2d;
  vecOfVector2d.emplace_back(Vector2d(2.0, 3.0));
  vecOfVector2d.emplace_back(Vector2d(4.0, 5.0));
  vecOfVector2d.emplace_back(Vector2d(6.0, 7.0));
  vecOfVector2d.emplace_back(Vector2d(8.0, 9.0));

  std::vector<std::function<bool()>> vecOfFunctors; // Store the functors for execution at a later point in time.

  for (std::vector<Vector2d>::const_iterator i = vecOfVector2d.begin(); i != vecOfVector2d.end(); ++i) {
    const Vector2d vec = *i;
    double xpos = rand() % 100; // Calculated but varies in each iteration

    std::function<bool()> isBBoxInsideFOVHorizontal = [FoV, xpos, vec]()->bool {
      std::cout << FoV << " " << xpos << " " << vec.x << " " << vec.y << std::endl;
      return true;
    };

    vecOfFunctors.push_back(isBBoxInsideFOVHorizontal);

    isBBoxInsideFOVHorizontal();

  }

  // This loop shows a delayed execution of the previously declared 
  for (const auto& func : vecOfFunctors)
  {
    func();
  }

  return 0;
}


Thanks for the reply. Could you please adapt the answer to account for the edited versions containing FoV as well? There are some constants I want this lambda to have access to as well. But more importantly, check Peter's comment above stating that "Creating the lambda in the loop with capture values requires creating a data structure containing copies of the captured values on each loop iteration, which has a cost and is unnecessary". This seems totally contradicting to "Code 1 and Code 2 are equivalent". Could you address this issue too since this is my train of thought as well?

I've added the FoV parameter, as you asked.
As for Peter's comment, it's actually not that clear, since it's highly compiler-dependent. If your compiler doesn't optimize at all, Version 1 might take slightly more runtime memory than Version 2, as it tries to create a new function object on each iteration of the loop, although it should also be releasing those resources immediately at the end of each iteration of the loop.
If your compiler does optimize, then as Alan commented, it'll just inline the code, since that functor is never used outside the loop.

Alan specifically said "non capturing lambdas" but Code 1 captures three variables. Isn't this contradicting?

His first sentence talked about the non-capturing lambda version, but his next sentence was talking about how all versions of the code will end up getting inlined during optimization because you're using those functions locally within the same scope immediately after declaration.
